# mybatis return id for inserted fields without object

Tags: sql-server, insert, mybatis

I know this question is asked several times but most of the answers are for the scenario when we are passing an object as parameter.

I am trying to insert a row into sql server using mybatis and I want the id of the inserted row.

I am not passing an object but raw variables like Integer, Long, Double

```
<insert id="insertUserSummary"  useGeneratedKeys="true" >
       INSERT INTO BRS_USER_SUMMARY
 (BRS_BRM_ID, BRS_USR_ID)
 VALUES
 (#{masterid}, #{userid} )    
</insert>
```

I am just passing masterid and userid in the calling function and it does an insert but I do not get id in return. Note- I am not passing an object as parameter but two variables.

Thank you.

Comment: I know nothing about MyBatis, but [this tutorial](http://www.raistudies.com/mybatis/inserting-auto-generated-id-using-mybatis-return-id-to-java/) seems to provide an answer: add `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to your XML mapping file. There is nothing in the SQL shown above that actually returns the new identity value (I'm assuming that your table has an identity column).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The tutorial is not what I am looking for as mentioned in the question as it is expecting object as parameter and I am working with raw parameters here.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the generated id from an `insert` query is to pass a map which will be used to hold the id of the generated row:

```xml
<insert id="insertUserSummary" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="id" keyProperty="idMap.id">
    INSERT INTO BRS_USER_SUMMARY (BRS_BRM_ID, BRS_USR_ID) 
    VALUES (#{masterid}, #{userid})
</insert>
```

Mapper:

```java
int insertUserSummary(@Param("masterid") int masterId, @Param("userid") int userId, @Param("idMap") Map<String, Integer> idMap);
```

Usage:

```java
Map<String, Long> idMap = new HashMap<>();
int affectedRows = mapper.insertUserSummary(42, 31415, idMap);
int insertedRowId = idMap.get("id");
```